# How can I customize a loess fit inside a levelplot in R

Tags: r, lattice, smoothing, levelplot, loess

I have created a levelplot in R that displays my data overlayed on a smoother contour plot using this code:

```
levelplot(chla_avg ~ lat * depth, trunc_level_test, ylim = c(275, 5), region = TRUE, col.regions = hcl.colors(110, palette = "spectral",rev=F), contour = FALSE, cuts = 100, panel = panel.levelplot.points) +
  layer_(panel.2dsmoother(..., n = 400, method = 'loess'))
```

This produces this image:
[levelplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X0K1.png)

I love this graph. It displays exactly what I want *except* I don't love the fit of the loess model. Normal I could customize `loess()` but I can't figure out how to get `panel.2dsmoother()` to take my arguments. Ideally I would like to change the `span` and `degree` arguments of `loess()` to make the fit a little less smooth.

I've tried:

```
levelplot(chla_avg ~ lat * depth, trunc_level_test, ylim = c(275, 5), region = TRUE, col.regions = hcl.colors(110, palette = "spectral",rev=F), contour = FALSE, cuts = 100, panel = panel.levelplot.points) +
  layer_(panel.2dsmoother(..., n = 400, method = 'loess(span=0.1)'))
```

Which produces this error:

```
Error using packet 1
could not find function "loess(span=0.1)"
```

Clearly `panel.2dsmoother` is reinterpreting the function in a way I do not understand.

In the `panel.2dsmoother` documentation it says: "the smoothing model is constructed (approximately) as `method(form, data = list(x=x, y=y, z=z), {args})`." ([panel.2dsmoother documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/latticeExtra/versions/0.6-29/topics/panel.2dsmoother)) I cannot figure out how to pass my arguments to the `loess` function.

Is there anyway to customize loess inside `panel.2dsmoother`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass extra arguments to the `loess` method using the `args` parameter of `panel.2dsmoother`. Just put the arguments inside a `list`.

Obviously, we don't have your data, but we can show the concept using the built in data set `iris`. First, we'll show the plot with the default arguments:

```r
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

levelplot(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width * Petal.Length, 
          iris,
          region = TRUE, 
          col.regions = hcl.colors(110, palette = "spectral", rev = F), 
          contour = FALSE) +
  layer_(panel.2dsmoother(..., n = 400, method = 'loess'))
```

[image]

Now let's use a smaller `span` value for our loess smoothing:

```r
levelplot(Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width * Petal.Length, 
          iris,
          region = TRUE, 
          col.regions = hcl.colors(110, palette = "spectral", rev = F), 
          contour = FALSE) +
  layer_(panel.2dsmoother(..., n = 400, method = 'loess', 
                         args = list(span = 0.2)))
```

[image]